# how do i change last digits 0 to 1 in java?

Tags: java

I am supposed to make an `if` statement program that changes the last digit to `1` if it ends in `0`.

input is a whole number.

**Example:**

```
12340 changed to 12341
1230320 changed to 1230321
```

Comment: `number%10==0? number+1: number`

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for last digit and if it is zero then add 1 to number.

```
if(number%10 == 0)
{ 
   return number +1;
}
return number
```